# How do you show that a Markov chain has not mixed?

Tags: markov-chain

I came across the claim that when doing Gibbs sampling, it is possible to show that a Markov chain has not yet mixed.  How is this done?

Comment: Which definition of "mixed"? The commonest is "within total variation distance $\delta$ of it's invariant distribution" (for some conveniently small $\delta$).  This is the basic problem of MCMC convergence diagnostics.  General tests aren't always that good in practice-- if you can give more details about your specific setting you might get better answers.

Comment: @P.Windridge: All I have is in the question.  If you can show that it hasn't mixed using any reasonable definition, that would be useful.

Comment: OK, I'll jot down some tests later (if no one else bites).  "Mixing" is also used informally in MCMC to mean "exploring the state space well" or "not getting stuck locally".

Comment: @P.Windridge: Yes, I'm definitely interested in how you can detect that you're not "exploring the state space well" or that you're "getting stuck locally".

Comment: apologies I'm bailing on attempting an answer.  I think there are a lot of ad hoc "tests", the most popular being "do some kind of plot and inspect it".